# OneToOne-Relation with Spring Boot Rest API and JPA => attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, jackson-databind

With my actual project I use Angular 6 for my frontend development and Spring Boot 2 for my backend development. The backend uses Spring Boot JPA for connection to a Postgres database, also I use Spring Boot Rest for creating the API, using the default endpoints created by Spring Boot Rest. So there are no handmade-Services or Controllers.

I have a Person-Entity and an Address-Entity with an oneToOne-relationship. All entities extend a BaseEntity:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    private UUID id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}
```

Person

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}
```

Address

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    private Person person;

    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
}
```

My repositories look like this:

```
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, UUID> {
}
```

and

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, UUID> {    
}
```

When posting

```
{
  "street":"exStreet",
  "housenumber":"121",
  "zipcode":"14321",
  "city":"exCity",
  "state":"exState",
  "person":{
    "lastName":"ExampleLastName",
    "firstName":"ExampleFirstName"}
}
```

to http://localhost:8080/addresses I always get the following error

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id
>   from null one-to-one property [Address.person];

together with

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id
>   from null one-to-one property [Address.person]

It looks like the server is not persisting the person-entity, and though there is no id to use for persisting the address-entity.
I try to achieve this:

frontend: angular form => service => call to httpclient with the shown json => post to spring boot rest api server // works, I think

backend: spring boot rest api server, deserializing json to an adress and a person-entity => address.setPerson(person) => saving via jpa to database

Is there a way to achieve this with some customization of jackson or something, or do I have to write services an controllers again, take care of linking, ...?
I am struggling with that for two days now, so every kind of help is much appreciated.

EDIT
After further investigation I am sure, that the problem is the mapping. But I do not know how to annotate my entities or what configuration needs to be done.

Comment: The error shows that the person field in Address, when saving it, is null. So it's not a mapping problem. You're just saving an Address which doesn't have a person. That said, your mapping doesn't make much sense either. Address is a BaseEntity. So, as per the mapping in BaseEntity, its ID is supposed to be generated using a UUID generator. But then you're also saying that its ID should be the same as its person ID. It can't be both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the problem is, that the person-part of the given json is not deserialized to a Person-Entity.

I removed 'extends BaseEntity' from my Address and created an @Id-Field, so that the id is not auto-generated, but the error still persists.
I am wondering what the correct way for saving a OneToOne-relation coming in via default Spring Boot Rest repository might be...

Comment: The error still persists because, as I said, the problem is that you're trying to save an address with a null person. That has nothing to do with the code you posted or with JPA. But everything to do with how you get/deserialize/create/populate your address in the above layer. You shouldn't keep wondering. You should use your debugger, or at least add traces in your code, to verify your assumptions.

Comment: I know that the problem is that I do not have a person for my address. The point is, that up to now I did not write any custom code to get/deserialize/create/populate my address. I defined the repositories and use the endpoints created by Spring Boot Rest. For non-nested objects this works perfectly fine. My problem is, that I do not know what to do to get a person-object from the given json. Creating of the address-object works (except the person-part).

Comment: Then tag your question with spring-data-rest. I don't know much about it (except that it does far too many things for me and doesn't let me in control enough, which is why I don't use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I managed to get that working. The Problem was indeed the Mapping.
I implemented a custom deserializer and registered it with @JsonDeserialize(using = AddressDeserializer.class) on the Address-Entity. See below.

```
@Component
public class AddressDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Address> {

    public AddressDeserializer() {
        super(Address.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Address deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode addressNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setLastName(addressNode.get("person").get("lastName").textValue());
        person.setFirstName(addressNode.get("person").get("firstName").textValue());
        System.out.println("##### ----- person.getLastName: " + person.getLastName());

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setPerson(person);
        address.setStreet(addressNode.get("street").textValue());
        address.setHouseNumber(addressNode.get("housenumber").textValue());
        address.setZipCode(addressNode.get("zipcode").textValue());
        address.setCity(addressNode.get("city").textValue());
        address.setState(addressNode.get("state").textValue());

        return address;
    }
}
```

Address-Entity:

```
...
@JsonDeserialize(using = AddressDeserializer.class)
public class Address extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
...
```

IntelliJ IDEA built-in HTTP-Client:
    POST http://localhost:8080/addresses
    Content-Type: application/hal+json
    Accept: */*
    Cache-Control: no-cache

```
{
  "street":"exStreet",
  "housenumber":"121",
  "zipcode":"14321",
  "city":"exCity",
  "state":"exState",
  "person":{
    "lastName":"ExampleLastName",
    "firstName":"ExampleFirstName"}
}
```

Result with resulting address:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/addresses

HTTP/1.1 201 
Last-Modified: Sat, 27 Oct 2018 13:50:16 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/addresses/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 27 Oct 2018 13:50:16 GMT

{
  "id": "89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834",
  "createdDate": "2018-10-27T13:50:16.803+0000",
  "createdBy": "testsystem",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2018-10-27T13:50:16.803+0000",
  "lastModifiedBy": "testsystem",
  "street": "exStreet",
  "houseNumber": "121",
  "zipCode": "14321",
  "city": "exCity",
  "state": "exState",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834"
    },
    "address": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834"
    },
    "person": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834/person"
    }
  }
}

Response code: 201; Time: 225ms; Content length: 693 bytes
```

Resulting person:

```
{
  "id" : "89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834",
  "createdDate" : "2018-10-27T13:50:16.808+0000",
  "createdBy" : "testsystem",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2018-10-27T13:50:16.808+0000",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "testsystem",
  "lastName" : "ExampleLastName",
  "firstName" : "ExampleFirstName",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834"
    },
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/89f57064-b4b4-4e1a-adae-142d8c09d834"
    }
  }
}
```

Database:

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESS;
CREATED_BY      CREATED_DATE    LAST_MODIFIED_BY    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE      CITY    HOUSE_NUMBER    STATE   STREET      ZIP_CODE    PERSON_ID  
testsystem  2018-10-27 15:50:16.803 testsystem  2018-10-27 15:50:16.803 exCity  121 exState exStreet    14321   89f57064b4b44e1aadae142d8c09d834

SELECT * FROM PERSON;
ID      CREATED_BY      CREATED_DATE    LAST_MODIFIED_BY    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE      FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME  
89f57064b4b44e1aadae142d8c09d834    testsystem  2018-10-27 15:50:16.808 testsystem  2018-10-27 15:50:16.808 ExampleFirstName    ExampleLastName
```

Thats it. Thanks for reading.